# Adding Text and Images in the same field in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uitextfield, swift5

I wanted to make a kind of a notes app where users can add images inline with text, similar to how iOS' native Notes app does. Any advice on approaches I could take for this?

I'm new to iOS development and have been trying to teach myself a bunch of necessary skills and was curious as to how someone would go about doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UITextField to add images and text in one field, It can be done by using storyboard also and to do it programmatically is also convenient.  Find the below code to add image programmatically in a text field :

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
var image = UIImage(named: "email.png")
imageView.image = image
emailField.leftView = imageView
emailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
emailField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 2):

[UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview) is your best bet. It is not the most friendly UI component to work with if you are just starting out, but it is what Apple almost certainly uses for their Notes App, and supports inlining of text, images, hyperlinks, styles etc.